# Return Featured Image for Each Post? (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm looking for some assistance in returning the featured image URL for each post on my website. The code I'm currently using only returns the value of the first post on the page.

Here's what I'm working with:

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID) ): ?>
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID), 'single post thumbnail'); ?>
<div class="comments-bg-image" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>'" </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you looping and changing `$post` each iteration?  Do the other posts on your site actually have thumbnails?

Comment: Yes every post has a thumbnail

Comment: This is the website for reference: http://palatehack.com . Any assistance would be appreciated, it's my first time doing php!

Comment: @J0e3gan see my response above thx

Answer (score 1):

WordPress' `wp_get_attachment_image_src` only takes specific string keywords for the `$size` parameter, which are:

- thumbnail
- medium
- large
- full

See below:

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) : ?>
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'large'); ?>
<div class="comments-bg-image" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>'"></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

At a glance, I noticed the closing `>` on your `div.comments-bg-image` element was missing, although I doubt that's the cause of the issue you're having. ;)

**Resources:**

- [Function Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src)

Comment: Thanks for this, however i've updated the code and the image still isn't updating for each post, still only providing the thumbnail of the first image.

Comment: Depends on how/where `$post` is assigned. Can you provide more of the code you're using? :)

Comment: Thanks!: <!-- post modal -->
<div class="show-post-modal">  
  <div class='modal-loading'>
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i>
</div>
<div class="modal-container">
  <div class="close-persistent-tooltip-body" id="close-persistent-tooltip"></div>
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'large' ); ?>
<div class="comments-bg-image" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')" >
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
<div class="comments-header">

    <div class="bottom">
      <div class="product-top">

Comment: Let me know if you need more @bluemwhitew

Comment: Take a look at [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) on WordPress' Codex. You'll need to ensure `$post` is set with the current post's data (which will include the image). :)

Comment: Any chance you can point me in the right direction from a code perspective? Im new to this haha thanks so much :)

Comment: I've tried a few more ways and still not having any luck. Any suggestions? Thanks :)